# Completablefuture starts only one thread. How to fix it?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

The goal is to receive the first result of the computation. But, I see if logs, that only one thread starts. How could it be fixed?

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3, new ThreadFactory() {
        int count = 1;
        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
            return new Thread(runnable, "my thread-" + count++);
        }
    });
    CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            if (findDecodedString(hash)) {
                return answer;
            }
            return null;

    },executor);

    CompletableFuture<Object> result = CompletableFuture.anyOf(future);
```

This function is called:

```
 private boolean findDecodedString(String str) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for (int lengthOfWord = 1; lengthOfWord <= 100; lengthOfWord++) {
            if (find(lengthOfWord, str)) {
                return true;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }
```

When I start it, only one **Thread-0** starts. How could I start more than one thread? How to stop all threads when one of them finds finished computation?

Comment: What exactly do you see in the log? The thread creation code doesn't log anything. So you're probably seeing *use* of the thread, not its creation. If you think otherwise, please [edit] the question, and add what you see in the log and why you think it indicates thread creation. Don't forget to format.

Comment: If you only want the first thread which finished. You can create a thread safe stack and push the result to this before any runnable finishes and do a blocking  stack.pop() call ?

Comment: "_The goal is to receive the first result of the computation_". Note your code only launches one asynchronous task, not multiple.